# Datalist on safari JS pollyfill

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, safari, mobile-safari, polyfills

I am creating a google script web app and i am trying to get data lists working on safari for mac and mainly IOS devices. the code below does work for a small data list, however i have over 30000 datalist entries i want it to show. the purpose of the data list is for it to show the matching entries when typing in a stock inventory ID number. for example typing in "B" would produce blue and black or typing in "ue" would show blue. the code works fine for a small list but when I enter in the entire 30000 inventory items it crashes on my ios device and takes forever to load on a mac safari. I believe it is due to the code having to "convert" each item into something else. My thought process is if I knew what it was converting the item into, I could just set the datalist objects as that from the get go. when I use this app on android or a windows computer, the 30000 inventory items appear instantly.;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Color Datalist</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" value="" list="colorlist" />
<datalist id="colorlist">
    <select style="display: none;">
        <option value="Black" />
        <option value="Blue" />
        <option value="Dark Green" />
        <option value="Grey" />
        <option value="Green" />
        <option value="Red" />
        <option value="White" />
        <option value="Yellow" />
    </select>
</datalist>
<script>
$window.load(function () {
    var nativedatalist = !!('list' in document.createElement('input')) && 
        !!(document.createElement('datalist') && window.HTMLDataListElement);

    if (!nativedatalist) {
        $('input[list]').each(function () {
            var availableTags = $('#' + $(this).attr("list")).find('option').map(function () {
                return this.value;
            }).get();
            $(this).autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
        });
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using polyfill, i used awesomeplete. awesomeplete worked great on safari, google chrome and edge!. to implement it, throw the js file onto your page then use the tags. their website gives alot of documentation and customisation options. http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/#basic-usage